# Owncloud - Proxy changes certificate

Tags: security, proxy, ssl-certificate, certificate, owncloud

I'm running an owncloud server 7.0.2 with apache(Ubuntu host) and configured it to use a self-signed ssl certificate. Everything works fine on my home-PC

On an other machine I would like to use the desktop-Sync client in Ubuntu which is behind a proxy. This proxy modifies the SSL Certificate and changes the certificate authority.

More presicely:
My Certificate: (When I access at home)
issed for: Me
Issued by: Me

Changed Certificate
issued for: Me
issued by: proxy operator

I'm not sure, but I think this is the Problem why I can't login at this machine. The log says the following when I try to login

http://pastebin.com/MUMdJYsy (German)
http://pastebin.com/ds5bETjC (English)
(Since it is a long log I used pastebin)

I think especially lines 9-12 are interesting, since this is the changed signer of the certificate. (Of course it is anonymized)

Do you have any ideas how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: could you please run with LANG=C locales? The german logs are not easily readable for most of us.

Comment: Sure. But it will take some time, since i'm not at home at the moment.

Comment: Line 9 says something like "the hostname cannot be found in the certificate's subject" - so yes, this might be the showstopper here.

Comment: I added the log in english